# ScopeGuard usage with multiple resourace allocatons and exit points in a fucntion

Tags: c++, raii, scopeguard

I have multiple resources allocated in a function, therefore quite a few pointers and out of which I have to return one pointer (let's say ret_ptr) and deallocate others (all othr_ptrs) before leaving the function.

I have multiple exit points in this function (where ret_ptr is 0 or it is pointing to a valid memory or an exception). Therefore before all the return statements and in the exception(catch block) I have to delete the othr_ptrs (doing multiple times in the function). Is there any way with "ScopeGuards" I could reduce the multiple clean-ups ?

```
X* func()
{
    try

    {
        A* a = new ..;
        B* b = new ..;


        if (something)
        {
            delete a;
            delete b;
            return 0;  // return NULL ptr  
        }

        X* x = new ..;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        delete a;
        delete b;
        return x; 
    }

    delete a;
    delete b;
    return x; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 If I make all unique_ptr except x, I don't need to explicitly delete them, right ?

Comment: Rigth, btw, I would use `std::unique_ptr` also for `x`... Even if you have to return `X*` and so use `x.release()`.

Comment: You might start by refactoring this into several functions.  This is clearly far to complicated to belong in a single function.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah that make sense..isn't this unique_ptr similar to the ScopeGuard ? Is there any advantage of using unique_ptr ?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is a RAII object which is standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `std::unique_ptr` (C++11), your example becomes something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<X> func()
{
    std::unique_ptr<X> x;
    try
    {
        std::unique_ptr<A> a(new A);
        std::unique_ptr<B> b(new B);

        if (something)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
        x.reset(new X);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return std::move(x);
    }
    return std::move(x);
}
```